# MCustomScrollbar not workink, jump to #id?

Tags: jquery, html, hash, scroll, href

sorry, but I dont't speak english. 
My problem: 
First page "a href":
page.html#anotherpageid

Second page not work together MCustomScrollbar. I read the text, but I dont understand.

```js
(function($) {
  var hash = window.location.hash
  href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*$/, "");

  $(document).ready(function() {
    if (hash) {
      $(window).scrollTop(0).scrollLeft(0);
      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState("", "", href);
      } else {
        window.location.href = href;
      }
    }
  });

  $(window).load(function() {
    $(".content").mCustomScrollbar();

    //scroll to location hash
    if (hash) {
      var target = $(hash).parents(".mCustomScrollbar");
      if (target.length) {
        target.mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", hash);
      }
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you Rory! :-)